# K8s argocd repo server is CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, cicd, argocd

For kubernetes , i used minikube and follow arcocd quick start guide. only argocd-repo-server is CrashLoopBackOff.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BtvR.png)

For kubernetes , i used minikube and follow arcocd quick start guide. only argocd-repo-server is CrashLoopBackOff.

Comment: Use `kubectl describe pod <pod-name> -n argocd` and copy the results to your question.

Comment: Well there is not much of information over here, clearly. try using ```kubectl describe po <pod> -n <ns>``` and ```kubectl get events -n <ns>``` to get a better understanding.

Comment: check the logs from pod by 

kubectl logs po <argocd-server-xxx> -n <your ns>